# Quão aceitável é usar "onde" com o significado de "em que"/"no qual"?

Tags: gramática

Sempre ouvi que usar "onde" sem o significado de lugar físico seria incorreto, um anglicismo (uma vez que em inglês o *where* é utilizado nesse contexto).

Por exemplo:

> O curso *onde* aprendi o alfabeto cirílico.

Ou também para descrever símbolos usados numa equação:

> *E* = *mc*²,
>   *onde* *E* é energia, *m*, massa, e *c* a velocidade da luz.

O correto, nos exemplos acima, seria "na qual", "em que", etc.

Procede, ou é um preciosismo?

Comment: stafusa, tentei tornar a pergunta mais clara e simples de ler; mas isto tem imenso a ver com estilo de escrita. Não te inibas de reverter! :)

Comment: Sem problema, @ANeves, acho que ficou melhor mesmo. :) Obrigado.

Comment: opinião pessoal - Nem mesmo um preciosismo, é de uso corrente mesmo.  Em física, principalmente,  "em que" soaria menos natural aos meus ouvidos do que "onde".

Answer (score 1):

Caso você pretenda escrever um texto que exija a norma culta da língua portuguesa, como em um texto dissertativo-argumentativo (redação do principal exame de admissão em universidades brasileiras, o ENEM), deve-se usar o onde apenas ao tratar de lugar. Entretanto, entre nativos, é bastante comum escutar o uso do onde em outras circunstâncias.

Comment: Oi Fred, bem-vindo ao Portuguese SE. É o que também já ouço falar há anos, mas você teria uma fonte recente afirmando isso?

Answer (score 1):

O mais correto, em termos gramaticais, como já foi dito, seria usar o "em que"/"na qual": [Onde, em que ou no qual?](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/onde-em-que-ou-no-qual/14487).

No entanto, pela minha experiência em comunicação científica, ainda que seja importante manter a correção gramatical, é mais importante ainda ser-se sucinto e eliminar locuções/expressões desnecessárias.
Em textos de teor científico, valoriza-se a brevidade, de modo a "deixar espaço" para aquilo que é mais importante - a discussão de resultados científicos.

Assim, se estamos a discutir o uso das expressões num contexto científico, é, de facto, um "preciosismo" e uma regra frequentemente ignorada (como neste artigo sobre a [Lei de Rayleigh Jeans](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lei_de_Rayleigh-Jeans)).

É necessário avaliar, caso a caso, o contexto em que se quer empregar a expressão.

Answer (score 0):

Isso depende de dois fatores:

1. O modo como você utiliza isso (informalmente ou formalmente);
2. O contexto.

Informalmente, qualquer uma das três opções (na qual, em que e onde) é aceitável nesse contexto. No entanto, formalmente é estabelecida a seguinte divisão:

1. Para se referir a locais utiliza-se **onde**;
2. Para se referir a outros substantivos utiliza-se **na qual, no qual, em que, cujo, etc.**.

Comment: Oi Chanp, minhas boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE. É o que também já ouço falar há anos, mas você teria uma fonte recente afirmando isso?

Comment: Possuo uma fonte, mas não tão recente (é de 2016): https://www.estudopratico.com.br/o-emprego-correto-de-onde-aonde-donde-no-qual-do-qual-e-em-que/ . Também encontrei uma de um site que algumas vezes utilizo para tirar algumas dúvidas acerca da lingua portuguesa: https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/onde-ou-em-que/

Comment: Obrigado, 2016 é recente o bastante, mas por fonte quero dizer fonte reconhecida.

Comment: Então, infelizmente não. Lamento!